# Why isn't the wallpapers changed when I upgrade to a beta release?

Tags: system-installation

I updated 13.10 Saucy Salamander to 14.04 through the terminal.  System settings says I am running 14.04 but I see nothing different.  The desktop wallpapers are all the same with Saucy Salamander. I didn't use a USB stick. Should I just re install?

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The `ubuntu-artwork` package should be updated, which also pulls in the `ubuntu-wallpapers` package (both should be at version 14.04)

Comment: When you upgrade Ubuntu, the wallpaper does not change. In fact, none of your settings changes. The new wallpapers should be installed and should be there for you. Just right click and change the wallpaper to whichever you want.

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: Yes I restarted.  I tried to change the wallpaper and there is no Trusty Tahr there.  I tried doing it through the graphical interface to update but that didn't work like it did between 13.04 and 13.10.  It says everything is up to date but I see no difference other than it says I have 14.04 when I log in.  Is there a way to check and repair broken stuff? I say stuff because I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the branding is the last thing Ubuntu does to the system installations. If you want your system completely rebranded, you should wait until the final release.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I was expecting too much from a beta release.

Answer (score -1):

Just open synaptic package manager and uninstall ubuntu-wallpaper saucy.  Worked for me.